# Continuously go from a lognormal distribution to a power law

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, statistical-mechanics

Do you know any phenomena that are described by a continuous mappings between a lognormal and a power law distribution?

Of course, one could give a simple linear combination of the two distributions; I am interested to mechanisms that actually arise in nature.

Comment: Maybe this is of interest for you: https://www.stat.berkeley.edu/~aldous/Networks/1089229510.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you impose a minimum boundary a Geometric Brownian Motion you get a power law distribution when solving the respective Fokker Planck equation.

You may look up Gabaix 1999 and Kesten 1973.